# How to "unsort" a DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` on my windows form which is bound to a `DataSource` like this:

```
using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SQL code here", sqlConnection))
{
    using (SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        dt1.Columns.Add("Select", System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));
        ds1.Tables.Add(dt1);
        ds1.Load(sqlDataReader, LoadOption.PreserveChanges, ds1.Tables[0]);
        dataGridView.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

Note the line which reads:

`dt1.Columns.Add("Select", System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));`

This adds a `boolean` column to the `DataGridView` represented by a `checkbox`. The `CellMouseClick` handler for the `DataGridView` looks something like this (in its barest form):

```
private void dataGridView_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Select"].Value = !dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Select"].Value;
}
```

Now, at some point I'd like to sort the `DataGridView` so that all the selected lines (i.e. those where the `checkboxes` have been checked) are at the top. So I call this function:

```
dataGridView.Sort(dataGridView.Columns["Select"], ListSortDirection.Descending);
```

And it works like a charm. The only problem is that from this point onwards, the `DataGridView` will automatically sort itself again when these values change. This is leading to confusing behaviour and I'd like to stop that. How can I tell the `DataGridView`, OK buddy, you're sorted now, thanks, now leave it as it is until I call the sort function again?

Comment: The simple solution would be "reload" the content of the View!

Answer (score 1):

Its not shown in the snippets, but is the column's `SortMode` property set to `Automatic`?  Try changing it to `NotSortable` or `Programmatic`:

```
dataGridView.Columns["Select"].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
```

Comment: I never set it to anything specifically but upon breaking the executing and inspecting the value it appears to be NotSortable by default. I've tried changing it to Programmatic but that doesn't seem to change the behaviour at all.

Comment: But is it still NotSortable after you set the sort?

Comment: If you are not setting the column's SortMode, could you define what you mean by "at some point I'd like to sort the DataGridView"?  What triggers "at some point"?